# Вопрос по SSH-Терминалу Pycharm

Tags: сервер, консоль, ssh, pycharm, exe

Пишу онлайн-приложение. Арендовал хостинг и создал на нем базу данных, к которой смог успешно подключиться с помощью Putty. *Пытаюсь повторить тот же успех, но с Pycharm: допустим, я подключусь через ssh-терминал пайчарма к серверу, а затем к базе данных.* По-идее, это будет работать с .py файлом, **но если я его переделаю в .exe, продолжит ли приложение подключаться к серверу?**

Comment: Если вдруг вы собираетесь делиться exe-файлом с другими людьми, то обычно это очень-очень плохая идея давать им полный доступ к своей базе данных и тем более ssh-доступ к серверу целиком

Comment: Я собираюст делиться exe, тогда как мне поступить? Или придется с Putty колдовать?

Comment: Обычно пользователям никогда не дают прямой доступ к базе данных. Вместо этого пользователи отправляют свои запросы на сервис, запущенный на сервере (обычно через HTTP, но можно и на голых сокетах сделать), а уже этот сервис формирует нужные запросы в базу и обращается к базе — и никто кроме этого сервиса не имеет прямого доступа к базе. Таким образом пользователи могут делать только что, что позволяет им делать сервис, и это всё более безопасно чем прямой доступ к базе

Comment: Или действительно стоит пытаться научить приложение ssh-соединению?

Comment: Я буду давать доступ к базе данных вовсе не прошаренным пользователям, а собственным одноклассникам, поэтому пока что попробую дать прямой доступ

Comment: Это проще для такого новичка как я

Comment: И среди этих одноклассников быстро найдётся тот, кто расковыряет ваш exe-файл, получит прямой доступ к серверу, удалит все данные из базы и установит биткоин-майнер на сервере — я сам был примерно таким одноклассником :)

Comment: Ну и ещё стоит вопрос удобства: если вы в базе что-то измените, работоспособность всех таких exe-файлов автоматически сломается и их все нужно будет переделать для работы с новой базой. Если между exe-файлом и базой будет стоять какой-нибудь промежуточный сервис, то достаточно будет только сделать обновление сервиса для работы с новой базой, а старые exe-файлы могут продолжить слать запросы к сервису в старом формате и обновлять их необязательно

Comment: Слава богу, что у меня нет таких одноклассников ))

Comment: Понял, если не смогу научить приложение ssh-соединению, то прибегну к сервису

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не продолжит.

Причина вот в чем:

Когда Вы создаёте базу данных на хостинге - то там в неком окружении начинает бежать процесс (процесс базы данных), который слушает определенный порт и принимает авторизованные подключения к базе данных по протоколу, который для этого предназначен.

Если настроить на хостинге видимость этого порта "снаружи" - то любой, кто знает, как авторизоваться в базе данных, сможет к ней подключиться. Но если Вы этой настройки не делали - то на помощь проиходит Putty.

При создании ssh-соединения через Putty у Вас создаётся зашифрованный канал, по которому вы "видите" сервер на хостинге не как "любой человек из интернета", а как localhost.

То есть, все настройки файерволов на стороне провайдера и на стороне самого сервера становятся для Вас несущественными. Это сделано для двух вещей: для "безопасности" (база данных не торчит на весь интернет) и для "единообразия" - всё настраивается примерно одинаково, меняется только номер порта.

Оборотная сторона этого упрощения коннекта - то, что нужен кто то, кто создаёт такой вот "зашифрованный канал связи" с сервером.

Итак, это умеют делать Putty, умеет делать среда разработки. Потому что это типичная задача, которая каждый день появляется перед разработчиком.

Но Ваше приложение, если не приложить дополнительных усилий, ssh-коннекта не устанавливает.

Теоретически, можно заморочиться и "научить" приложение всем тем же вещам, которые делают Putty и PyCharm. Думаю, при этом надо гуглить на тему "python ssh-connection"

Вообще, если бы Вы добавили подробности - например, о какой базе данных идёт речь - было бы проще писать ответ, используя уже специфичные для БД термины.

Comment: Да я терминов пока не пойму, только вчера вечером узнал о том, что такое база данных

Comment: ну, в любом случае Вы работаете с определенной базой данных, скорее всего - MySql, Postgres или MongoDb. Успехов Вам!

Comment: Спасибо! И вам того же!